# Does SQLite 'merge' prefixes used by LIKE?

Tags: sqlite

I have a query like

```
select * from tbl where name like 'a%' or name like 'abc%';
```

Does SQLite search 'a%' and 'abc%' separately? Would it check abc% is included by a%, and do only one search?

"explain query plan" returns

```
"0" "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE traces USING PRIMARY KEY (name>? AND name<?)"
"0" "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE traces USING PRIMARY KEY (name>? AND name<?)"
```

Is it what happens at run time?

Answer (score 1):

> Does SQLite search 'a%' and 'abc%' separately? Would it check abc% is
>   included by a%, and do only one search?

I think **neither** is the correct answer as it appears to be in-between the two options given.

---

I think trawling through the documenting will explain a little.

First port of call is [The SQLite Query Optimizer Overview](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html) . This says :-

> If the WHERE clause is composed of constraints separate by the OR
>   operator then the entire clause is considered to be a single "term" to
>   which the OR-clause optimization is applied.

Addiotnally in [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://sqlite.org/eqp.html)  it states :-

> If the WHERE clause of a query contains an OR expression, then SQLite
>   might use the **"OR by union" strategy** (also described here).

- ***link included below to 1.8. OR-Connected Terms In The WHERE Clause***

> In this
>   case there will be two SEARCH records, one for each index, with the
>   same values in both the "order" and "from" columns. For example:
>
> ```
> sqlite> CREATE INDEX i3 ON t1(b);
> sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE a=1 OR b=2;
> 0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE t1 USING COVERING INDEX i2 (a=?)
> 0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE t1 USING INDEX i3 (b=?)
> ```

So it very much appears that the **"OR by union" strategy** is being used as you have:-

```
"0" "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE traces USING PRIMARY KEY (name>? AND name<?)"
"0" "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE traces USING PRIMARY KEY (name>? AND name<?)"
```

**Or-clause** optimization, is explained here:-
[3.0 OR optimizations](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html#or_opt) (same as first document). However there are lots of *mights*, rather I think that link as provided in the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN to [1.8. OR-Connected Terms In The WHERE Clause](https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#or_in_where) is more pertinent, this includes :-

> **1.8. OR-Connected Terms In The WHERE Clause**
>
> Multi-column indices only work if the constraint terms in the WHERE
>   clause of the query are connected by AND. So Idx3 and Idx4 are helpful
>   when the search is for items that are both Oranges and grown in
>   California, but neither index would be that useful if we wanted all
>   items that were either oranges or are grown in California.
>
> ```
> SELECT price FROM FruitsForSale WHERE fruit='Orange' OR state='CA';
> ```
>
> When confronted with OR-connected terms in a WHERE clause, SQLite
>   examines each OR term separately and tries to use an index to find the
>   rowids associated with each term. It then takes the union of the
>   resulting rowid sets to find the end result. The following figure
>   illustrates this process:
>
> [image]
>
> The diagram above implies that SQLite computes all of the rowids
>   first and then combines them with a union operation before starting to
>   do rowid lookups on the original table. In reality, the rowid lookups
>   are interspersed with rowid computations. SQLite uses one index at a
>   time to find rowids while remembering which rowids it has seen before
>   so as to avoid duplicates. That is just an implementation detail,
>   though. The diagram, while not 100% accurate, provides a good overview
>   of what is happening.
>
> In order for the OR-by-UNION technique shown above to be useful, there
>   must be an index available that helps resolve every OR-connected term
>   in the WHERE clause. If even a single OR-connected term is not
>   indexed, then a full table scan would have to be done in order to find
>   the rowids generated by the one term, and if SQLite has to do a full
>   table scan, it might as well do it on the original table and get all
>   of the results in a single pass without having to mess with union
>   operations and follow-on binary searches.
>
> One can see how the OR-by-UNION technique could also be leveraged to
>   use multiple indices on queries where the WHERE clause has terms
>   connected by AND, by using an intersect operator in place of union.
>   Many SQL database engines will do just that. But the performance gain
>   over using just a single index is slight and so SQLite does not
>   implement that technique at this time. However, a future version
>   SQLite might be enhanced to support AND-by-INTERSECT.

Another consideration is [4.0 The LIKE optimization](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html). However, I believe this is on a per LIKE clause basis only.